# insert large string into json object

Tags: php, mysql, json, xcode, filter

i have problem when insert large string into json
i need to make sure there would be no mistakes when insert this large string into json object by filter the article from special characters like (!@#$%^&*()\|';:./) and smile faces before insert it

for example
if i have this json

```
{
  "Article": "article text"
}
```

and this in xcode

```
- (IBAction)SendArticleButton:(id)sender {
     NSString *Article       = ArticleTextField.text;
     NSString *ArticleJson   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Article={ \"Article\": \"%@\" }",Article];
     NSData *PostData = [ArticleJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/InsertJson.php"]];

[request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:PostData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];



}
```

php code

```
$Article = $_POST['Article'];

          header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 
$con    = mysql_connect("xxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxx");
          mysql_select_db("xxxxx", $con);
          mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$Article = utf8_encode(trim($Article));

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `xxxxx`.`xxxxx` (`id`, `Article`) VALUES (NULL, '$Article');");
```

Comment: Use `base64_encode()` when inserting the value in the database. For example:

`$Article = base64_encode(utf8_encode(trim($Article)));`
`mysql_query("INSERT INTO `xxxxx`.`xxxxx` (`id`, `Article`) VALUES (NULL, '$Article');");`

Comment: would you try writing the $Article in a file before and also after you call the header() function, and also without utf8_encode(). 
Please share the results what you get